# Compare all columns from two tables and get the changed columns name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table with same column name and most of the values are same for the every primary key. For some primary key some values are different. I want to capture the list of column names that its values are different from the other table.

For example, lets say I have two tables A_old and A_new

**A_old**

[image: A_old]

**A_new**

[image: A_new]

**I want output like below**

[image: Output]

I need a better approach to do this. I dont need the full query.. All I need is a better approach. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Apart from `mysql` and  `sql`, A bit mix there. What other tag should be added . like PHP, JAVA , because i believe the response you are expencting is a dynamic response from a page

Comment: What tool set are you using?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Both simultaneously?  Is one table in MySQL and the other in SQL Server?

Comment: Both tables are in SQL server only. I am removing the mysql tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the below query would give the desired rows.

```
    SELECT 
    AO.col1
    ,List_of_changes = 
         CASE 
         WHEN AO.col2 = AN.col2 AND AO.col3 = AN.col3 AND AO.col4 = AN.col4 THEN 'NO CHANGES'
         WHEN AO.col2 <> AN.col2 AND AO.col3 <> AN.col3 AND AO.col4 <> AN.col4 THEN 'col2, col3, col4'
         WHEN AO.col2 = AN.col2 AND AO.col3 = AN.col3 AND AO.col4 <> AN.col4 THEN 'col4' 
         WHEN AO.col2 = AN.col2 AND AO.col3 <> AN.col3 AND AO.col4 <> AN.col4 THEN 'col3, col4' 
         WHEN AO.col2 = AN.col2 AND AO.col3 <> AN.col3 AND AO.col4 = AN.col4 THEN 'col3'  
         WHEN AO.col2 <> AN.col2 AND AO.col3 = AN.col3 AND AO.col4 = AN.col4 THEN 'col2' 
         WHEN AO.col2 <> AN.col2 AND AO.col3 <> AN.col3 AND AO.col4 = AN.col4 THEN 'col2,col3' 
         WHEN AO.col2 <> AN.col2 AND AO.col3 = AN.col3 AND AO.col4 <> AN.col4 THEN 'col2,col4' 
--and so on
         END 
    FROM
    A_old AO
    INNER JOIN A_new AN ON
    AN.col1 = AO.col1
```

Here I think * can be replace with CASE statements to see which columns match in the matching row and generate the values you want.

Comment: Let me try this approach and if It works I will mark it as answer. Thanks..!

Comment: What if I have some 20+ columns.. Is there any alternative approach ? cant we update the list_of_changes using concat function for every case when statements.. ?

Comment: I can understand 20+ columns would create too many case statements to handle. I haven't looked into alternative approach yet. I will try to find time to look into it.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM a_old
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM a_new
)  t
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY col1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use even dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = 'select t1.col1, ' + STUFF((SELECT
    '+ case when t1.' + column_name + ' = t2.' + column_name + ' then '''' 
    else ''' + column_name + ''' end '
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'A_new'
AND column_name <> 'col1'
ORDER BY column_name
FOR xml PATH (''))
, 1, 2, '') + ' as list_of_changes from A_old t1 join A_new t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1';

SELECT @sql = 'select t.col1, case when len(t.list_of_changes) = 0 then ''No changes'' 
              else t.list_of_changes end as list_of_changes 
              from(' + @sql + ')t;';

EXEC (@sql);
```